# In Hadoop-1.0.4 with Hbase-0.94.3 ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: Retried 7 times

Tags: hadoop

ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: Retried 7 times

Here is some help for this command:
List all tables in hbase. Optional regular expression parameter could
be used to filter the output. Examples:

hbase> list
  hbase> list 'abc.*'

Answer (score 0):

Offcourse, your HBASE master server is not running. You have to configure it in hbase-site.xml.